# How to filter an integer using the sort in twig

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, twig

I want my project to be filter by the score and I am using a elasticsearch. now, the score have two variables: matchingScore and personalityScore. this two is should be added in the twig to get the actual score. Now, I dont know how to sort an integer since this is not an array and the sorting in the twig is required an array. This is the sample code:

```
{% for provider in matches | sort matchingScore[provider.id] + personalityScore[provider.id]('desc') %}

                    {% if matchingScore[provider.id] + personalityScore[provider.id] >= score_criteria %}
```

Please Help me. thanks.

Comment: Can't you do the sort in your controller?

Comment: You could create a twig extension if you really want to do it in Twig.